# How to manage ammo when firing and reloading

Tags: unity

I have this script and I need to fix one thing which is count correctly the number of bullets I have.

```
public GameObject ebullet;
public Transform Bullet_position, target;

public int ammo = 200;
public int ammo_Hold = 600;
public bool reload = false;
public bool readyToShoot;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    if (ammo == 0)
    {
        ammo_Hold = ammo_Hold - 200;
        ammo = 200;
    }

    if (reload == true && ammo_Hold >=0)
    {
        ammo_Hold = ammo_Hold - ammo;
        reload = false;
    }

    if (readyToShoot == true)
    {

        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - transform.position);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * 5.0f);

        GameObject bullets = Instantiate(ebullet) as GameObject;
        bullets.transform.position = Bullet_position.transform.position * 1;
        Rigidbody rb = bullets.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.velocity = transform.forward * 100;
        Destroy(bullets, 2f);
        ammo--;

    }
    else
    {
        print("Don't Shoot");
    }

} // end update
```

Comment: I don't understand, what's the problem? This isn't a question that can be answered if we don't know what the problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, I believe you are using `ammo` as the ammo that has been loaded, and `ammo_Hold` as the ammo remaining in the player's inventory. So the player should be able to fire 200 rounds before they have to reload, and they can do this up to 4 times since they have 200 rounds + 600 in the inventory. Please correct me if I have this wrong. I made some slight modifications to your code below without overhauling how it was written.

First of all, you want a variable to keep track of the magazine size. In your case, it is 200. We will call this `magazineSize`. When the player reloads, you want to subtract the number of rounds that were used from `ammo_Hold`. As it is written, you are subtracting the number of *unused rounds* from the player's inventory. We can use `(magazineSize - ammo)` to figure out the number of rounds that were used.  Also, add a check to avoid ammo_Hold from going negative.

```
if (reload == true && ammo_Hold >=0)
{
    if (ammo_Hold >= (magazineSize - ammo))
    {
        ammo = magazineSize;
        ammo_Hold = ammo_Hold - (magazineSize - ammo);
    }
    else
    {
        ammo = ammo + ammo_Hold;
        ammo_Hold = 0;
    }

    reload = false;
}
```

Also, when ammo reaches 0 I don't think you want to blindly load the player's gun with 200 rounds. You want to add as much to `ammo` as you can without going over how much you have remaining in `ammo_Hold`. Add a simple check to handle this.

```
if (ammo == 0)
{
    if (ammo_Hold < magazineSize)
    {
        ammo = ammo_Hold;
        ammo_Hold = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        ammo = magazineSize;
        ammo_Hold = ammo_Hold - magazineSize;
    }
}
```

Finally, you should add a check to see if you have any ammo available before firing.

```
if (readyToShoot == true && ammo > 0)
```

**Complete Code:**

```
public GameObject ebullet;
public Transform Bullet_position, target;

public int magazineSize = 200;
public int ammo = 200;
public int ammo_Hold = 600;
public bool reload = false;
public bool readyToShoot;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{

    if (ammo == 0)
    {
        if (ammo_Hold < magazineSize)
        {
            ammo = ammo_Hold;
            ammo_Hold = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            ammo = magazineSize;
            ammo_Hold = ammo_Hold - magazineSize;
        }
    }

    if (reload == true && ammo_Hold >=0)
    {
        if (ammo_Hold >= (magazineSize - ammo)) //Check if you have enough ammo to do a full reload.
        {
            ammo = magazineSize;
            ammo_Hold = ammo_Hold - (magazineSize - ammo);
        }
        else
        {
            ammo = ammo + ammo_Hold;
            ammo_Hold = 0;
        }

        reload = false;
    }

    if (readyToShoot == true && ammo > 0)
    {

        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(target.position - transform.position);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime * 5.0f);

        GameObject bullets = Instantiate(ebullet) as GameObject;
        bullets.transform.position = Bullet_position.transform.position * 1;
        Rigidbody rb = bullets.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        rb.velocity = transform.forward * 100;
        Destroy(bullets, 2f);
        ammo--;

    }
    else
    {
        print("Don't Shoot");
    }

} // end update
```

Comment: Thank you so much for all this. You cleared many things to me. Just one thing I need you to look at it again please. In this part [   if (reload == true && ammo_Hold >=0)
] If I i reload, ammo value not change. example, ammo = 120 and i relaod it.It should be 200 but it keeps 120 !! I tried to solved....could you check it please.

Comment: Ah I see the problem. I left out the part where `ammo` is updated.  I have updated my answer with modifications to that section of code.  You'll want to check if you have enough bullets remaining in `ammo_Hold` to fully reload.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (ammo == 0)
{
    ammo_Hold = ammo_Hold - 200;
    ammo = 200;
}
```

If ammo_Hold is not a multiple of 200 it will break.

```
if (reload == true && ammo_Hold >=0)
```

Not really important and it comes to preference I think but `reload` is a boolean so basically you check `true == true` or `false == true`,
so instead you can just type `if (reload && ammo_Hold >=0)`.

```
if (readyToShoot == true)
```

Same thing. Also I don't where you set it to be true.

Another thing, you use `Update` instead of `fixedUpdate`, this means someone with a higher frameRate can shoot faster then someone with a lower frameRate.

About the question...
It would be better to work with timing.
It happens that the unity time example is also about shooting!

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-time.html

In case the docs ever break, here (part of) the code referenced from the link.

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject projectile;
    public float fireRate = 0.5F;
    private float nextFire = 0.0F;
    void Update() {
        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && Time.time > nextFire) {
            nextFire = Time.time + fireRate;
            GameObject clone = Instantiate(projectile, transform.position, transform.rotation) as GameObject;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you are back to the bullet problem again.
Before you shoot you can check if `Ammo > 0`.
Within the shooting you can check if it reaches 0.
If it does I would set a boolean `reload_required` to `true`.
But I leave that up to you as an exercise. I hope it helps.

Comment: Good point. thank you for giving me option to add new things into my script.